# Expect integer in dimensionFilter of GA4 Api

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I want to find most visited sites which includes **my/path**.

I can get the most visited pages across the system so I want to add a filter to this request. When I add this filter I get the following output:

```
[Exception]
Expect integer.
```

This is my filter:

```
'dimensionFilter' => new FilterExpression([
    'filter' => new Filter([
    'field_name' => 'fullPageUrl',
    'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
        'value' => 'my/path',
        'match_type' => 'CONTAINS'
        ])
    ])
])
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found an answer. Instead of 'CONTAINS', I edited as:

Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::CONTAINS

Which is actually an integer.